# Sri Lanka to Bahamas, how can we travel without visa in February?

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas, routes

This is for 2 Sri Lankan nationals (Sri Lankan passports) and we want to travel to Bahamas (would prefer Nassau) and would like to transit without visa in February. Is there a way to do this? We would like to keep to a maximum of 4 flights (connecting flights where we have to get off count).

I examined all the routes I could find and the best one I have so far is CMB (Sri Lanka) to SVO (Russia) to CCC (Cayo Coco Cuba). From CCC however, there are no flights to Havana and we would have to take a taxi/bus.

Comment: Yesterday Cuba announced new flight restrictions starting next week and mandatory quarantine. Plus interprovincial travel is restricted. I do not think your Cayo Coco > Havana option is feasible https://www.usnews.com/news/world/articles/2021-01-30/cuba-to-quarantine-travelers-amid-covid-19-surge

Comment: It does sometimes feel like people are inhabiting an alternate reality

Comment: "we want", "we would prefer", "we would like", "we would like". Well, you *could* simply take current events into account, and you *could* realize that it's probably a bad idea to travel that far if you do not absolutely *have to*.

Comment: There are so many questions like this, also from Indian citizens, you'd think some Indian airline would notice and begin direct service (with a stopover in Europe, most likely).

Comment: @Strawberry Try living in the US ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [Flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/nas/routes), NAS currently has connections with airports in the following countries:

- USA - requires visa
- Canada - requires transit visa
- Cuba (Havana and Holguin) - the most flexible TWOV
- Jamaica - TWOV requires you to remain airside
- Haiti - TWOV requires you to remain airside
- Turks and Caicos - TWOV requires you to remain airside
- Panama - TWOV requires you to remain airside

All the TWOV which require you to remain airside are only applicable if you have both flights on the same ticket, which seems to be very unlikely.

Holguin only has flights to Havana and Cancun. We've seen previously that you probably can't TWOV in Cancun.

Havana has flights to:

- Port of Spain, Trinidad and Tobago - flexible TWOV
- Mexico City (not at the moment)
- Cancun (see above)
- Nicaragua - visa required
- Panama - see above
- Colombia - TWOV requires you to remain airside
- Venezuela - TWOV requires you to remain airside
- Argentina - TWOV requires you to remain airside (exceptions can be made but require the airline to escort your and be responsible for you, forget about it)
- United States - See above
- Spain, Italy, France, Switzerland - visa required
- Dominican Republic - TWOV requires you to remain airside

Port of Spain has flights from (other than the above):

- Curaçao - Flexible TWOV
- Guyana - TWOV requires you to remain airside
- Suriname - TWOV requires you to remain airside
- Sint Marten - ?
- Antigua and Barbuda - TWOV requires you to remain airside
- Barbados - TWOV requires you to remain airside
- A few other islands with no interesting connections

Other than the above, Curaçao has connections to:

- The Netherlands - visa required

So, no, there don't seem to be any easier options, at least at this time (there may be more options in normal "post-COVID" times).

Note however, that even for the very very few countries which allow flexible TWOV (like Russia and Cuba in your itinerary), I'm not sure any airline is going to let you board a flight to a destination where you're not allowed to enter, if you don't have an onward flight on the same ticket. To them, your final destination is the one on their ticket, and you need to be able to enter that destination. Since all those flights are on different tickets and different airlines, I would be very surprised if you ever got to your final destination.

I think the best option for you is probably to get a transit visa (probably several, actually) which would give you more options regarding routing.

If you have the means to travel to the Bahamas, it shouldn't be difficult to get a transit visa for many of the alternatives.

Good luck!

NB: I hope you're not trying to go there on holiday. Travelling for leisure at this time is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: Also I would say there is a not too small chance of not beeing able to come back before summer. I wouldnt be surprised of stronger flight restrictions soon.

Comment: @lalala I agree, personally if I were planning to travel anywhere at all in the next couple of months at least, I wouldn’t do it unless I could get a direct flight *and* I was prepared, willing and able to cope with a (possibly lengthy/costly) delay to my intended return. The advent of vaccines plus the concerns about new strains seems for the time being to be adding further uncertainty to an already complicated travel situation

Comment: @Traveller personally I wouldnt go further than one land border (difficult for Sri Lanka, I know). I know some ppl which almost got stuck on some islands (all direct flights home were suspended the week after their flight). Maybe there would have been a way back, but I think one should only do it if 'plan C' (staying for a couple of month) is an option.